# checkinstall package in Debian Buster

Tags: debian, checkinstall

New Debian was released but without `checkinstall` package - https://packages.debian.org/stretch/checkinstall .

Was this package deprecated - what is the replacement?

Or can we expect this (is it normal for other packages too?) package to be released for Debian Buster later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to:

https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/debian-26/how-to-check-why-%27checkinstall%27-is-no-longer-available-in-%27testing%27-424319/

and

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=878487

there is some issue with the package and it will/should be released for Debian Buster soon.

Package availability can be view here:

https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=checkinstall

**UPDATE 22-Jun-2019**

thank to Steve Gelman the `checkinstall` package for `Debian Buster` is now available thru `buster-backports` repo.